# Upload CSV or Excel file in Angular 8 and show the data(columns and rows) of file in grid as preview in Angular 8 - without external libraries

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried with this snippet in VS Code/Angular 8. I tried to find solutions for this scenario but no luck so far. Please help me with this.

In **app.component.ts** file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'sampleApp';
  public fileString;

  changeListener($event): void {
    this.readThis($event.target);
  }

  readThis(inputValue: any): void {
    var file: File = inputValue.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
    var texto = reader.result;
    var temp = texto.toString().split(',')[1];
    console.log(temp);
    }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

In **app.component.html** file:

```
<div>
  <input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)" #input accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I believe, I need to get JSON Object to show the data in grid. So How to convert `temp` variable data to JSON Object ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you gettting in console.log(temp);

Comment: can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-read-table-xhyqzp

Comment: I am getting this in the console. ```   UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA........

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Sorry. I don't want to use external libraries. But that's cool.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: I got solution for that

Comment: @venkatk Can you pl share the solution here as an answer.